# cryptography in windows mobile application

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I'm doing windows mobile wireless application using visual studio .net(c#). So I want to add encryption for remote login over TCP connection(using c#). So are there any way to add cryptographic functionalities in our mobile application? or are there any libraries for windows mobile applications?

Comment: You didnt specify what platform.. [Win7 supports SSL for WCF](http://www.michelvandervlugt.net/PermaLink,guid,05664e33-0fde-4aa7-8c04-99e4c5647f8b.aspx)

Comment: If you mean Windows Mobile and .NET CF, then our SecureBlackbox .NET edition ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-security.php ) offers comprehensive security and encryption functionality and it can be used with .NET CF.

Answer (score 0):

So you want end to end  encryption for a TCP connection. It sounds like you want to use [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). Just make sure validate who you are opening the connection with ( either use a certificate from a CA or use a self signed one and make sure you only ever talk to that certificate). [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150597.aspx#Y1492) should get you pointed in the right direction.